# IndexError: index 201 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 201

Tags: python, arrays

I know this is a common error but I can't seem to make sense of the source of the problem from the traceback from running this script of mine.

Basically, this script will produce two csv files that consist of a printout of a series of 0.5s and 1s to form a 201x161 print out generated from the script itself. Not to go into too much of details, but what the script does is that there are 201 positions per 'frame'. For 161 'frames', a value of 1 are given to the 10 listed positions (in the pos list). These 10 positions are updated every frame so the value of 1s would be added to changing positions each 'frame'.

What the script does is not so important, but I'm hoping for a keen eye who can help me identify the issue that is generating that error.

```
from numpy import random, pi, sin
import numpy as np
from csv import DictWriter
import csv

#fixed stim size from George's AdelsonBergen.m
stim_x = 201 #(x axis)
stim_t = 161 #(y axis)

CONspeedRAW = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
SINspeedRAW = [0.0, 0.00077066656671800611, 0.0015365817177795569, 0.002293023331585725, 0.0030353276940450328, 0.0037589182519216719, 0.0044593338288080528, 0.0051322561297608583, 0.0057735363650253425, 0.0063792208287037815, 0.0069455752746670745, 0.0074691079394238937, 0.00794659107000374, 0.0083750808241273289, 0.0087519354199731905, 0.0090748314236410669, 0.0093417780738945227, 0.0095511295558659819, 0.0097015951480526573, 0.0097922471800438275, 0.0098225267519174118, 0.0097922471800438275, 0.0097015951480526573, 0.0095511295558659837, 0.0093417780738945244, 0.0090748314236410669, 0.0087519354199731923, 0.0083750808241273306, 0.00794659107000374, 0.0074691079394238963, 0.0069455752746670754, 0.0063792208287037824, 0.0057735363650253434, 0.0051322561297608591, 0.0044593338288080537, 0.0037589182519216727, 0.0030353276940450341, 0.0022930233315857263, 0.001536581717779558, 0.0007706665667180073]

NrOfDots = 10

counter = 0 #Counter for pos list
counter2 = 1 #Counter for speed list
counter201 = 0 #Counter for stim_matrix
rowcounter = 0 #Counter for writer
a = 0 #Counter for pixel to matrix speed scaling
printpos = True

SINspeed = []
CONspeed = []
floatPOS = []
frameList = []

#Set file name for output data file which includes participant ID and the experiment time and date   
createfile = open('SinMatrix.csv', 'wb')

matrixwriter = csv.writer(createfile,
                        quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

#pos = np.array([random.uniform(0.,201.) for r in range(NrOfDots)])
pos = np.array([random.randint(0,201) for r in range(NrOfDots)])
pos2 = pos

stim_matrix = 0.5 + np.zeros((stim_t,stim_x)) 

#Sine Speed Generator
for x in SINspeedRAW:
    a = x*330
    SINspeed.append(a)

for x in SINspeedRAW:
    a = (x*330)*-1
    SINspeed.append(a)

print 'pos1', pos

#Convert int to float if not you can't add in decimal speed
for x in pos:
    floatX = np.float(x)
    floatPOS.append(floatX)

for x in range(stim_t):
    #Update each stim_matrix's line with 1 for 10 dots placement
    for x in range(len(pos)):
        stim_matrix[counter201,pos[counter]] = 1
        counter += 1
    counter = 0

    #Add generated sin speed to position of the 10 dots 
    for x in range(len(pos)):
        if floatPOS[counter] + SINspeed[counter2] >= stim_x:
            floatPOS[counter] = 0.
        if floatPOS[counter] + SINspeed[counter2] <= 0:
            floatPOS[counter] = stim_x
        floatPOS[counter] = floatPOS[counter] + SINspeed[counter2]
        counter += 1
    counter = 0
    counter2 += 1

    for x in pos:
        pos[counter] = round(floatPOS[counter])
        counter += 1
    counter = 0
    counter201 += 1    

    #Print data for the current trial into a line of text
    matrixwriter.writerow(stim_matrix[rowcounter,:])
    rowcounter += 1

    if counter2 == 40 and printpos == True:
        print 'pos2', pos
        printpos = False
    if counter2 == 80:
        counter2 = 0

createfile.close()

counter = 0 #Counter for pos list
counter2 = 1 #Counter for speed list
counter201 = 0 #Counter for stim_matrix
rowcounter = 0 #Counter for writer
a = 0 #Counter for pixel to matrix speed scaling
printpos = True

print floatPOS

floatPOS = []
#---------------------------------Sin Matrix done. Now to generate Con Matrix-----------------------------------

#Set file name for output data file which includes participant ID and the experiment time and date   
createfile = open('ConMatrix.csv', 'wb')

matrixwriter = csv.writer(createfile,
                        quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

stim_matrix = 0.5 + np.zeros((stim_t,stim_x)) 

#Con Speed Generator
for x in CONspeedRAW:
    a = x*330 #33
    CONspeed.append(a)

for x in CONspeedRAW:
    a = (x*330)*-1 #33
    CONspeed.append(a)

#Convert int to float if not you can't add in decimal speed
for x in pos2:
    floatX = np.float(x)
    floatPOS.append(floatX)

print 'Cons pos1', pos2

for x in range(stim_t):
    #Update each stim_matrix's line with 1 for 10 dots placement
    for x in pos2:
        stim_matrix[counter201,x] = 1

    #Add generated cons speed to position of the 10 dots 
    for x in range(len(pos2)):
        if floatPOS[counter] + SINspeed[counter2] >= stim_x:
            floatPOS[counter] = 0.
        if floatPOS[counter] + SINspeed[counter2] <= 0:
            floatPOS[counter] = stim_x
        floatPOS[counter] = floatPOS[counter] + CONspeed[counter2]
        counter += 1
    counter = 0
    counter2 += 1

    for x in pos2:
        pos2[counter] = round(floatPOS[counter])
        counter += 1
    counter = 0
    counter201 += 1    

    #Print data for the current trial into a line of text
    matrixwriter.writerow(stim_matrix[rowcounter,:])
    rowcounter += 1

    if counter2 == 40 and printpos == True:
        print 'Cons pos2', pos2
        printpos = False
    if counter2 == 80:
        counter2 = 0

createfile.close()
print floatPOS
```

*EDIT: Traceback message: Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-10f6fe655e0a>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Aaron/Desktop/Stimulus Matrix Sandbox/Stimulus Matrix Gen 1.0.py', wdir='C:/Users/Aaron/Desktop/Stimulus Matrix Sandbox')

  File "C:\Users\Aaron\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Aaron\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/Aaron/Desktop/Stimulus Matrix Sandbox/Stimulus Matrix Gen 1.0.py", line 66, in <module>
    stim_matrix[counter201,pos[counter]] = 1
```

Comment: Index 201 is one outside of the length of a list of size 201... Lists are zero indexed, so you only have indexes 0..200

Comment: one can hardly tell where the error is coming from without a traceback

Comment: ^Added the traceback message. ^^ I see what you mean. But the strange thing is, sometimes I was able to generate the plots smoothly without an error whereas other times, I get that indexing issue. It can't be that the size of the array changing because it is always the same. This is what confuses me.